# command line curl timeout parameter

Tags: curl, command-line, timeout

I am using command line curl program and interestingly I could not find a timeout parameter for command line curl. I read the man pages for curl and googled but still could not find one. The `libcurl` has timeout parameters(`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`) but that is not what I am looking for. I am looking for the command line curl timeout parameter.

There is `--max-time` parameter which is for maximum amount of time to keep the connection open and `--connect-timeout` which is for the connection phase of curl, but none for the normal timeout.

Does anyone know about this parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by "normal timeout".

Comment: say I am trying to download a big file with curl and say it takes 1 hour to download. So I should set the timeout to more than 1 hr. That is the timeout I am referring to.

Answer (score 34):

Option `--max-time` does exactly what you need: "Maximum time in seconds that you allow the whole operation to take". You just think wrong about it.

```sh
# 10 seconds for the full operation to complete
curl --max-time 10 https://example.com
```

Answer (score 4):

On un*x, you have the timeout command. try :

```
timeout -s SIGTERM 3600 curl --your arguments here
```

send a SIGTERM after 3600 seconds to end if, if it honors it. 
Always better than a brutal SIGKILL by default who may corrupt your file downloaded at 99% :¬)

Comment: Two problems with this.  (1) this timeout will apply to the entire curl operation including DNS resolution, connection and waiting for reply.  Using the `--connect-timeout` and `--max-time` params provides more granular control and keeps the flow of control in `curl` itself; and (2) on every *nix I checked, the correct syntax is `-s SIGTERM` or `--signal=SIGTERM`, not `-SIGTERM`.